# perl compile error

Tags: perl

The following code errors out:

```
 if (! defined $dchash{$location}) {
    die "Unrecognized realm: $location";
    }
 elsif ($dchash{$location}) ne $realm) {
    die "Incorrect realm for host in $location, expected $dchash{$location} got $realm";
    }

syntax error at ./test.pl line 73, near ") ne"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What is the proper syntax for verifying $realm is in the hash?

Comment: There is one ")" to much in you code. Remove it.

Comment: -1 for not reading the very obvious error message you got...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `)` character on your `elsif` line is causing the problem. Removing that should eliminate that syntax error.